# Adding a new item to a RecyclerView when button is clicked?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, model, adapter, android-recyclerview

I just started using RecyclerViews but i cant completely understand how to add or remove items from it. Below i will attach my adapter code it is a test code and everything in the layout works fine. I feel like im also writing too much unnecessary code so any tips or criticism is appreciated.

```
public class PlatesAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<PlatesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    //Declaring a List<> of Plates
    private List<Plates> mPlates;
    int amountOfPlates;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Declaring Buttons and textViews
        public TextView plateWeightTextView, amountOfPlatesTextView;
        public Button addButton, subButton, addLayoutButton;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //initializing Buttons and TextViews
            plateWeightTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plate_weight_value_textView);
            amountOfPlatesTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_of_plates_textView);
            addButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            subButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtract_button);
            addLayoutButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public PlatesAdapter(List<Plates> plates) {
        mPlates = plates;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View PlatesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plate_item_layout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(PlatesView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlatesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final TextView textView2 = holder.amountOfPlatesTextView;

        //BUTTONS add 1 or subtract 1 from amountOfPlates;
        Button button = holder.addButton;
        Button button2 = holder.subButton;

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                amountOfPlates++;
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(amountOfPlates));
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                amountOfPlates--;
                textView2.setText(Integer.toString(amountOfPlates));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPlates.size();
    }
```

Here is my Model Layer which i feel is completely wrong but im not 100% sure if it is.

```
  public class Plates {
    private int mPlateWeight;
    private int mAmountOfPlates;

    public Plates() {
        //mPlateWeight = plateWeight;
        //mAmountOfPlates = amountOfPlates;
    }

    public int getmPlateWeight() {
        return mPlateWeight;
    }

    public int getmAmountOfPlates() {
        return mAmountOfPlates;
    }

    public static List<Plates> createPlateList() {
        List<Plates> plates = new ArrayList<>();

        plates.add(new Plates());

        return plates;
    }
}
```

This is where im comfused. Its were do i call the addPlates or addItem method and what do i pass to it? Below is my main activity. I Just dont know where to add these addItems or addPlates methods is it to the Model Layer or the Adapter?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

Button mButton;

private List<Plates> mData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Button to add layout to recyclerView
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //Adapter LayoutManager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.weights_recycler_view);
            PlatesAdapter adapter = new PlatesAdapter(mData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do with RecyclerViews is to add a method to set the data.
In your example :

```
public void setPlates(List<Plates> plates) {
  mPlates = plates;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}`
```

You can also add a getter if you want to verify if the data have changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method in your adapter to add a Plates in the arrayList and to notify the change.
Something like:

```
public void addPlates(Plates plate) {
  if (mPlates == null) mPlates = new ArrayList();
  mPlates.add(plate);
  //notifyDataSetChanged();
  notifyItemInserted(mPlates.size()-1)
}`
```

Comment: This is where im confused. Where do i call addPlates? in an onClickListener for the button that is supposed to add the item to the list?

Comment: You have to call adapter.addPlates in the event where you want to add an item. If you want to add an item clicking the button call it in the onclicklistener method

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `createPlateList` method is not needed.
You should add a method in your adapter that looks like this:

```
public void addItem(Plates plate)
{
    mPlates.add(plate);
}
```

Since your adapter works with this list, all you need to do to add or remove items, is to add/remove the items from your list. After all you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter so it knows data was changed in your list.